# "Send" a tag to its death

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [send](/questions/tagged/send) tag has over 700 questions tagged with it. It's very ambiguous, for obvious reasons. Mostly dealing with sending data or emails, and mostly used as a meta-tag. Browsing through a couple pages of the tag, I see no valid uses of the tag that require retagging.

If anyone knows of any valid retags that should take place, please speak up.
Otherwise, this tag needs destroyed.

Comment: That's just cruel. I mean, what would [receive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/receive) do without [send]?

Comment: Clearly they'll both have to go.  What a shame.  \*cough\*

Comment: Arent there *many* tags that are ambiguous ? New, delete, and a lot of common operations are ambiguous in the same way as send or receive.

Comment: @AshRj: So find them and request them to be killed. I, personally, can only request tags be killed that I actually come across. I don't actively search for them, just notice them naturally while cleaning things up in review, etc.

Comment: But the thing is that these *are basic operations* across many languages so those tags *are needed*.

Comment: No, they're not. All they do is waste space.

Comment: @AshRj: my personal benchmark is: can I imagine someone subscribing to such a tag? And I simply can't think of anyone thinking "Gee, I sure want to know about every question about 'sending' that anyone asks on SO".

Comment: @JoachimSauer No but C + Memory-Management + New / Delete is a very specific topic which someone might subscribe to